# Trace of finite-order matrix over $\Bbb C$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots-of-unity

> Suppose that $A\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ is such that $A^m=Id$ for some $m\in
> > \Bbb N$, is it true that if $Tr(A)\in \Bbb R$ then it must be an integer? Here, $Tr(A)$ denotes the sum of the elements in the
>   diagonal of $A$

I've been trying to solve certain problem and if this were true, I'd be done.

**My approach:** I know that the eigenvalues of $A$ will be roots of unity, and that the trace is the sum of such eigenvalues. The problem then reduces to show that *any sum of roots of unity (not necessarily with all sumands being different) that lies in $\Bbb R$ is an integer*. I have not found any counter example to this so I'm assuming it's true, however, I can't find how to prove it. Any ideas please? Thanks!

Comment: You should write $A^{\color{red}m}=I$, not $n$.

Comment: I think this result is false. If $A=\begin{pmatrix} \zeta_n&0&0&0\\ 0&\zeta_n&0&0\\  0&0&\zeta_n&0\\ 0&0&0&\zeta_n\end{pmatrix}\in M_4(\Bbb C)$, where $\zeta_n^4=1$ and $\zeta^2\neq \pm1 $ (i.e. $\zeta_n=\pm i$), So, $A^4=Id$, but $Tr(A)=4\zeta_n\notin \Bbb R$ .

Comment: @carlosarturoHurtado The problem is about the case in which $Tr(A)\in \Bbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not true in general. Consider any matrix of the form $\left( \begin{array}{clcr} \cos{\frac{2 \pi}{n}} & \sin{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\\-\sin{\frac{2 \pi}{n}} & \cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}} \end{array} \right)$, for $n$ a positive integer.
This is a matrix of finite order $n$, which certainly has real trace. However,
its trace is usually not an integer (eg it is not for $n = 5$ or $n = 7$).

It is true that if a matrix of finite order has rational trace, then that trace is an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, simple counter example. My problem comes from a bigger context, I'll see if I have enough hypothesis to ensure that the trace is rational, maybe that can work. Thanks!

Comment: If there isn't some way to prove it is rational, your chances of proving it to be an integer seem somewhat slim :)

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot. Indeed, in my problem, it is not necessarily an integer. I could prove my original problem bt other means. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad your "real" questions (whatever it was) got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If one adds $\zeta_8$ to $\overline{\zeta_8}$, one doesn't get an integer. So a diagonal matrix consisting of these will have real trace, it will have order $8$, and its trace will not be an integer.

Comment: I believe you get 1

Comment: I'm am pretty sure that $\zeta_6 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$

Comment: I believe this trick does work when one picks $\zeta_{8}$, though; the choice of $\zeta_{6}$ seems to be unlucky :)

Comment: It works with $\zeta_{n}$ whenever $\phi(n) > 2$, where $\phi$ is Euler's function.

Comment: However for $n = 3,4,6$, (and for no other $n$), we have $\phi(n) = 2$

Comment: Whoops! :) -----